# XUnit nuget failing (visual studio 2013) xunit.core already has dependency defined

Tags: visual-studio-2013, specflow, xunit, xunit.net

When doing a Nuget for XUnit.Net I get:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.core (= 2.0.0-rc1-build2826)'.
'xunit.core' already has a dependency defined for 'xunit.extensibility.core'.
```

I get the same when tryting to Nuget Specflow.XUnit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I changed the Nuget option (up on top left above the the results and to the left of search) back from {include prerelease} to {stable only} everything works ok.

I needed the {include prerelease} for installing the {xunit.runner.visualstudio} which lets you run tests in the *visual studio Test Explorer* available from the Visual studio menu: ***Test/Windows/Show Test Explorer***.

Answer (score 24):

If you want the prerelease version, you need to *update NuGet itself*.

> Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates > Visual Studio Gallery.

Comment: I also had  to Clear Package Cache and then [Restore] from Manage Nuget packages from solution